# .htaccess rewriterule for folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, directory

I'm trying to redirect using the link: `http://www.mysite.com/af/2` to `http://www.mysite.com/af/2/`, but I can not perform this procedure, the link `/af/####` corresponds to a user ID and is a folder.

You can accomplish this using .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rule like the following will take care of that:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

The condition is to prevent urls that already end with a slash to match this rule. The rule will match everything `^` and redirect it to the same url with a slash behind it.

Comment: I put this in the .htaccess file, my question now is, for this work i have to put this code only??

Comment: You have to make sure `mod_rewrite` is enabled,, the options allow it to alter the url and the `RewriteEngine` is `On`.

Comment: I tested using a development server and is perfectly working the problem in the production of this server, it is running plesk [link](http://kb.parallels.com/en/114425).